# Conditional operator expression issues C2445 starting with MSVC 19.29 (VS16.11)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, language-lawyer, c++20

This program [no longer compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/Kn3bb7jEM) under `/std:c++20`<sup>1</sup>, starting with MSVC 19.29 (VS16.11):

```cpp
struct X {
    X(int) {}
    operator int() { return {}; }
};

int main() {
    true ? 42 : X(1729);
}
```

The compiler diagnostic reads:

> ```
> error C2445: result type of conditional expression is ambiguous: types 'int' and 'X' can be converted to multiple common types
> note: could be 'int'
> note: or       'X'
> ```

That seems reasonable given that `X` implements a conversion constructor that can implicitly convert from `int` to `X`, and a user-defined conversion function that can implicitly convert from `X` to `int`.

Compilers seem to agree on this, too:

[GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/4czxzGajf)

> ```
> <source>:7:10: error: operands to '?:' have different types 'int' and 'X'
>     7 |     true ? 42 : X(1729);
>       |     ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> <source>:7:10: note:   and each type can be converted to the other
> ```

[Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/198qec83c)

> ```
> <source>:7:10: error: conditional expression is ambiguous; 'int' can be converted to 'X' and vice versa
>     7 |     true ? 42 : X(1729);
>       |          ^ ~~   ~~~~~~~
> ```

#### Question

Is this a valid C++ program? If it isn't, why not?

#### Bonus Question

What's the guidance for library authors<sup>2</sup>? Is being [`explicit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) about construction sufficient? If so, why?

---

<sup>1</sup> *This used to compile in [previous versions](https://godbolt.org/z/1bcaEYdzE) and still does when using the [`/permissive` compiler option](https://godbolt.org/z/17xMfM5zs).*

<sup>2</sup> *`X` has the same properties as MFC's [`CStringT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class) class template.*

Comment: I wonder if `CStringW` has new capabilities that are only enabled under C++20?

Comment: @MarkRansom good question, I need to check this. OTOH I seriously doubt that Microsoft does more than merely maintaining compatibility of the MFC library.

Comment: The [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) is crazy complex. Evaluation of the type of the expression follows six rules, with sub- and sub-sub-rules, culminating in a note that reads *"This section is incomplete"*. At a guess, `E2 : E3` could be converted into `wchar_t const*` or `CStringW`, and either conversion is equally prioritized. This could be a bug in your code, a bug in the library, a bug in the compiler, or a language defect. This is hoping that you can afford a [tag:language-lawyer] because a language lawyer you need.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/oedEx69G1) is an attempt at reproducing the issue that doesn't repro. Feel free to play around with it.

Comment: Whelp, I nailed it: [C++17](https://godbolt.org/z/9K4nGzcE8) vs. [C++20](https://godbolt.org/z/87hYY3f54). A professional can take it from here.

Comment: Close voter: I'd be interested why you need debugging details. There is a [mcve] with all necessary explanations...

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for the edit, I don't recognize the question anymore, but it is much better now. A shame I cannot upvote here....

Comment: The problem occurs with Yes (/permissive-).  I cannot reproduce your problem in  VS2022 with   /permissive.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT as written in the question: with `/permissive` it compiles with later versions than 19.29.

Comment: @IInspectable: Those are not the rules.  They are a summary paraphrasing the rules (and an incomplete one, as you noticed).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is ambiguous per [[expr.cond]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.cond#4.sentence-5) because implicit conversion sequences can be formed from either `:` operand to the other's type. There is no ranking applied to these conversion sequences.

MSVC before C++20 implicitly uses `/permissive`, which makes several behavior non-conforming to the standard, which seems to happen here as well.

This particular issue can be avoided by making either the constructor or conversion function `explicit`, in which case it can't be used in an implicit conversion sequence.

Generally I would recommend avoiding conversion functions if there is no good reason that an equivalent normal member function call wouldn't suffice.

I would also recommend making both constructors and conversion functions `explicit`, except if you intent the user to e.g. pass an `int` to a function taking `X` or pass an `X` to a function expecting `int` and that would make sense transparently had the user assumed the function takes the other type instead. That's certainly not the case with `int` and a string type.

If both constructor and conversion function are `explicit`, then the conditional operator will again fail, this time because neither conversion sequence can be formed. But I think that's good. A string and `int` are not equivalent. The user should state explicitly which type they want.